# Can UK doctors legally prescribe drugs online?

Tags: united-kingdom, medical

The online pharmacy [Kiwi Drug claims](http://www.kiwidrug.com/regulation/) to dispense drugs legally from their online NHS-affiliated doctors, who prescribe drugs online.

> Kiwi Drug provides an online doctor service through its UK affiliate,
>   which is registered with the Care Quality Commission to provide
>   prescriptions online.
>
> Prescriptions are dispensed by an NHS pharmacy regulated by the
>   General Pharmaceutical Council.
>
> Kiwi Drug's affiliate's doctors are GMC registered. Most are
>   experienced GPs. They are all trained in providing prescription
>   medicine online. The doctors are individually responsible for the
>   prescriptions they issue. Registered pharmacists are responsible for
>   dispensing.

Assuming the pharmacy's claims are true, is it actually legal for a doctor to give prescriptions based on an online "consultation" in the UK?

Comment: Yes. It's what you might call a legal scam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. The Care Quality Commission is the regulatory body that oversees the adherence of private medical practitioners to health industry standards, regulations and laws.

The [Health and Social Care Act 2008](http://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/markup.cgi?doc=/uk/legis/num_act/2008/ukpga_20080014_en_1.html) confers broad powers on the Care Quality Commission to regulate health and social care services.

The [The National Health Service (Pharmaceutical Services) Regulations 2005](http://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/markup.cgi?doc=/uk/legis/num_reg/2005/20050641.html) provides for electronic prescriptions to be issued. In the definitions:

> "**electronic  prescription**" means an electronic  prescription  form or an electronic repeatable  prescription ;
>
> "**electronic prescription form**" means a  prescription  which falls within paragraph (b) of the definition of " prescription  form";
>
> "**prescriber**" means a doctor, dentist, independent nurse prescriber or a supplementary prescriber;
>
> "**prescription form**" means-
>
> (a) a form provided by a Health Board, a Health and Social Services Board, a Local Health Board, a Primary Care Trust, an NHS Trust or NHS Foundation Trust, and issued by a prescriber; or
>
> (b) data that are created in an electronic form, signed with a prescriber's advanced electronic signature and transmitted as an electronic communication to a nominated dispensing contractor by the ETP service,
>
> to enable a person to obtain pharmaceutical services or local pharmaceutical services, and does not include a repeatable  prescription;